# printing all the array value

Tags: java

```
class ArrayApp{

    public static void main(final String[] args){

     long [] arr; 
     arr= new long[100];
     int i;
     arr[0]=112;
     arr[1]=111;
     for(i=0;i<arr;i++) {
     System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }

  } 
}
```

I get this error,

```
ArrayApp.java:10: operator < cannot be applied to int,long[]
        for(i=0;i<arr;i++) {
                 ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the size of the array, which would be `arr.length`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
```

As of Java 1.5, you can also use the for each loop if you just need access to the array data.

```
for ( long l : arr )
{
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

arr is an object of `long[]` , you can't compare `int` with it.

Try `arr.length`

Alternatively You should go for

```
for(long item:arr){
System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `arr.length`

Comment: Now if i want to show only the values which are filled and not show the rest of blocks which dont have any value.

Comment: Then have a check before printing the value, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The question has to be seen in the [context of a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184696/deleting-an-item-from-array)!

From this former question I remember that you actually have a logical array inside a physical array. The last element of the logical array is *not* `arr.length` but `2`, because you've "added" two values to the logical array.

In this case, you can't use `array.length` for the iteration but again need another variable that store the actual position of "the last value" (`1`, in your case):

```
long[] arr; 
arr= new long[100];
int i;
arr[0]=112;
arr[1]=111;
int nElem = 2;  // you added 2 values to your "logical" array
for(i=0; i<=nElem; i++) {  
  System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

**Note** - I guess, you're actually learning the Java language and/or programming. Later on you'll find it much easier to not use arrays for this task but `List` objects. An equaivalent with `List` will look like this:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(112);
values.add(111);
for (Integer value:values)
  System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Long arr = new Long[100];
 arr[0]=112;
 arr[1]=111;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  if (arr[i] != null ) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

if you want to show only those which are filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using one line of code:
Arrays.asList(arr).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "\n");

See http://java.dzone.com/articles/useful-abuse for more similar tricks.